# Actionscript 3.0 Rotating a sprite around its center point

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, sprite, center, degrees

I searched online and found this script that is supposed to rotate and image but I'm not sure how to use, where to put in the degree angle that I want my sprites to rotate by.
Also, I get an error. **1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before leftparen. 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before leftbrace.**

```
var point:Point=new Point(spr_box.x+spr_box.width/2, spr_box.y+spr_box.height/2);
rotateAroundCenter(spr_box,45);

function rotateAroundCenter (ob:*, angleDegrees) {
    var m:Matrix=ob.transform.matrix;
    m.tx -= point.x;
    m.ty -= point.y;
    m.rotate (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
    m.tx += point.x;
    m.ty += point.y;
    ob.transform.matrix=m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

fix the function to this

```
function rotateAroundCenter (ob:*, angleDegrees) {
    var m:Matrix=ob.transform.matrix;
    m.tx -= point.x;
    m.ty -= point.y;
    m.rotate = (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180)); // was a missing "=" here
    m.tx += point.x;
    m.ty += point.y;
    ob.transform.matrix=m;
}
```

The `45` in your code is the degrees that you want to rotate by, just change that value.

Comment: For the record, rotate is a function, there should be no =